# cassandra cqlsh cannot show custom attribute of a column_family

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

Let's say I have a column_family named `kv` and I want to add a custom attribute `new_attribute` to table, so it will show like this when I use command `desc table kv`

```
CREATE TABLE ks1.kv (
    k text PRIMARY KEY,
    v text
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'ALL'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE'
    AND new_attribute = ***;
```

Please notice that the last line. I want to show that. But it seems that when issuing command `desc table kv`, cqlsh won't send the string to cassandra server. Instead it seemingly fetch results from python cassandra library. How should I let cqlsh support that ? (Assume I've already implement such attribute in the cassandra server)